# How can I add multiple rows in a CSV, but overwrite every time the script is run?

Tags: python, csv

So I am running a script which pulls data for 60 different items, for easy use i want to store this data in a csv file. Every time i run the script i want to store all 60 items and then overwrite all previous data. When i run it at the moment using the 'w' argument it only adds the very last item it pulls. If i change it to 'a' it will add all 60 items however it will not overwrite when i run it next. Any help is appreciated!!

```
import os, random, csv

vin = '1600'
n = 1
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'\\sorion-app01\Shares\ProcessData\Broadcasts\Good'):
   for filename in files:
        if not 'XX' or not '0X' or not 'XXXXXX' or not '000X' in filename:
            f = os.path.join(path, filename)
            vins = str(f)[50:67]
            if not 'X' in vins[13:17]:
                vin = int(vins[13:17])
                if vin > 1600: 

                    from sys import platform
                    import pyodbc

                    if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
                        print("linux")
                        driver = 'mydriver.so'

                        conn = pyodbc.connect(
                            driver = driver,
                            TDS_Version = '7.2', # Use for
                            server = 'aserver',
                            port = 1433,
                            database = 'TraceDB',
                            uid = 'EXTUser',
                            pwd = 'EXTPass!')

                    elif platform == "win32":
                        #print("Win32")
                        conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=database')


                   #pull the data here#

                    with open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
                        filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                                                quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator = '\n',)
                        header = [('column1'), ('column1'), ('column2'), ('column3'), ('column4'), ('column5')]
                        if not csvfile:
                            filewriter.writeheader(header)
                        filewriter.writerow([data, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6])

                        n=n+1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're re-opening the file every time round the loop; you want to open it before the loop and close it after the loop.

Comment: Yep of course! I should have seen that, thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

Overwriting it as a empty file at the very beginning of your code works for you?

```
import os, random, csv

with open("file.csv", "w") as my_empty_csv:   
         pass 


vin = '1600' n = 1

[...]
```

Best!